# Restricting Administrator Access to Sharepoint Document Library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I work in an highly sensitive environment where management want to restrict admin access to the documents uploaded to the library.

The site collection admins should not be able to view the documents in the library.

Can this be achieved?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of SharePoint 2007, there is a distinction between windows/domain administrators and SharePoint administrators - windows admins are not necessarily SharePoint admins.

So, you can create a special "SharePoint admin" account which is only used for administering the SharePoint server. Split its password between an administrator and a key user and you're done - only together they will be able to do changes in SharePoint and the admin without the key user won't be able to access documents.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, a user specifically given site collection admin access will be able to access anything in the site. That's why you gave them that power. If you want to have someone with more or less site collection admin access to everywhere but the one library, you will need to do the following:

1. Remove them as a site collection admin.
2. Add them to the root with Full Control access.
3. Go to the library and make it stop inheriting permissions from the site at large.
4. The list of permissions will still be the same but now if you remove the user's Full Control access, it will only go away for that one library.

The other thing to watch out for is that if you give someone access at the web application level, as in through CA, that access supersedes any access restrictions you place on them within the site.

Comment: what do u mean by : "Add them to the root"

Comment: Add the user in question to the root SPWeb of the site collection. If you have a site collection called http:\\yoursite.com\site, this would be the SPWeb with the same name (http:\\yoursite.com\site). Since by default permissions cascade down from the root, if you haven't stopped inheriting permissions on any subsite, anyone given Full Control access to this site will get Full Control access to all subsites.